# How to assign the git rev-parse output to ENV variable in dockerfile?

Tags: git, docker-compose, dockerfile, git-rev-parse

I am trying to add versioning to my program, and I want the version string to be the short commit hash of my repo.

The following command gives me exactly the string I want: `git rev-parse --short HEAD`.

So far, I was able to set it as an environment variable by having the following lines in my Dockerfie:

```
ARG VERSION_NUM
ENV VERSION_NUM=$VERSION_NUM
```

And the following build command: `docker-compose build --build-arg VERSION_NUM=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)`

In my main.py I have this assignment and it works: `VERSION_NUM = os.environ.get('VERSION_NUM', 'local_version')`

But now, I need to change the code and find another way to do this without passing the `--build-arg` when building the container.

What is the correct way to do so? CI\CD-wise and practice-wise..

I have tried two methods so far:

1. I created a set_version.sh script that exports the variable (the short commit hash) - but it did not take place.
2. I created a get_version.sh script that outputs the variable but I wasn't able to assign it to an ENV variable.

Answer (score 0):

I did this work outside the `docker build` pipeline, and passed the value in as an `ARG`.

Apologies this is in PowerShell but I'm not much good at Bash. I'm sure you can translate to something useful to you though.

```
dotnet tool install --global GitVersion.Tool
$version = dotnet-gitversion | convertfrom-json | select -exp Semver

docker build -t "my-app:$($version)" --build-arg "VERSION_NUM=$($version)"
```

UPDATE: I made a guess how you'd do without gitversion:

```
$version = (git rev-parse --short HEAD)

docker build -t "my-app:$($version)" --build-arg "VERSION_NUM=$($version)"
```

Comment: Thank you. I was already able to pass the argument from outside , now I am trying to create it on the fly inside the build.

Comment: I don't think you can. Each layer in an image is created in a new container. Even if you used RUN to execute a script to set an environment variable, I don't think it would persist to the next layer, and you'd need to have git in your base image.